# Why is the Xcode icon red?

Tags: macos, xcode

Today I noticed a very odd thing: the Xcode app icon on my system has changed to red. It seems really odd as the entire icon is the same, just that the color is red!

[image: Red Xcode App Icon]

Comment: Did you follow the tips given at http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-dock-icon-to-xcode-to-distinguish-multiple-versions/ or perhaps download a copy from someone who did?  The icon looks exactly like the sample at http://skelimon.tumblr.com

Comment: What version of OS X are you running? Might be relevant.

Comment: @AlanShutko - I didn't do anything like this

Comment: @ChristianCorrea - I am on 10.8.5, I just updated the SMC update yesterday before that it seemed fine.

Comment: Does clicking on the icon launches the app? Have you tried removing the dock icon and re-adding it?

Comment: I tried to remove it and place it back again, still the same. I checked in the Application folder and it's still the same, So it's not just on the dock

Comment: Turns out that it was a prank by a coworker, I will be removing the question!